# Delete all the space at end of each line in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to delete all the spaces and tabs at the end of all my lines.

I use following methods:

```
string.replace("\\s+$", "");
```

here, "\s+$" is a regex expression

It seems it' right. However the fact is I would not delete it.

The string is:

```
               a) AAAAAA.                        
           b) BBBBB.
           c) CCCCCC.
           d) DDDDD.
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `trim()`?

Comment: Please provide more info on why you did not use trim()

Comment: trim also delete beginning spaces. I don't want to do that

Comment: @chrylis pretty clear in the question: **at the end of all my lines**.

Comment: Why is this downvoted with no reason?

Comment: @m0skit0 I wanted to make sure that trimming the leading whitespace was a problem; that's why it was a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
string.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

- `String#replace()` does not take a regex as argument.
- You need to double escape `\s`

*EDIT*: yes it does work:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String a = "     AAAAAAAA             ";
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll("\\s+$", ""));
}
```

Maybe your confusion is that you think `a.replaceAll()` will modify String `a`. Strings in Java are immutable (they cannot change). `a.replaceAll()` will return the modified String.

*EDIT2*: If you're using a multiline String, `"\\s+[$\n]"` regex should do the work.

Comment: @liangwang Yes, it does work. I added a simple example of it working.

Comment: I think this does not work for multiline Strings. Try running it with final String a = "   AAAAA    \n BBBB   \n"; and see. Bohemian's does work.

Comment: Of course this doesn't work in multiline strings. I don't see anywhere where is this specified as multiline. I will add multiline support.

Comment: @JeroenWarmerdam, i tried on "\\s+[$\n]", it does not work. Yes, I'm working on multiline strings

Answer (score 4):

Use `replaceAll()`, which uses regex to find its target, rather than `replace()`, which uses plain text for its target.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)\\s+$", "");
```

Here I've added the `(?m)` switch that makes carat and dollar match before/after newlines, which you'll need to make it work given the multi-line input.

Answer (score -1):

```
Delete all the space at end of each line in Java
```

I guess you need [String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method

use

```
string.trim()
```

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Comment: Trim will delete white spaces both at start and end.

Comment: Yes,I saw the first example that `a)aaaa` is also not aligned properly.I guess OP need it.